# How to do this %x:~0,1% in %%x (for) batch-file

Tags: loops, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

my `%%x` are

```
a=23
b=56
c=89
```

in a `.txt` called `hi.txt`

```
for %%x in (hi.txt) do (echo %%x:~0,1 %%x)
```

but it failed....

thank you

i want to echo "the first character" in each line, but i cant use %%x:~0,1...

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do... I'm assuming that you want to parse the file hi.txt and pull out the variables (a,b,c) and the number they are equal to..

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (hi.txt) do (
   echo  %%i has value %%j
)
```

this will output

```
 a has value 23
 b has value 56
 c has value 89
```

See "help for" if you need more info.

Also note, my example is parsing on the = sign, so it doesn't matter how wide each variable is.  You could have a line like "MyText=100" and it would work too.  Your ~0,1 assumes each value is only 1 character wide.

I hope this helps.

Comment: just in case someone has made a variable that looks like `a=b=c` your tokens would miss the rest of the line. change it to `tokens=1*` and you get everything after the first `=` in %%j

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is print the first character of a line, then the following script should work.  I believe your original issue may have been with Delayed Variable Expansion.  See "help setlocal" and "help set" for more information.

This version of the script reads each line into a temp variable and snips the first character into another variable named firstCharacter.  The ! are used for the delayed variable expansion feature of CMD scripts.

```
    @echo off
    setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS,ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    for /f %%i in (hi.txt) do (
       set wholeLine=%%i
       set firstCharacter=!wholeLine:~0,1!
       echo First Character is !firstCharacter!
    )

    endlocal
```

and the output is...

```
 First Character is a
 First Character is b
 First Character is c
```

I wasn't able to find a way to use %%i directly for this, hence the temporary variable wholeLine.  I added the variable firstCharacter for clarity, but it doesn't need to exist for this to work.  I could have echoed !wholeLine:~0,1! directly.

Have fun.